# Asterisk SIPPeers Permission Denied

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Am trying to use asterisk by posting via http to get the peers, and i keep getting permission denied and then the remote server is not accessible or disconnected, though the login action is working fine and the manager.conf persimission is set correct to allow read and write.
Here is the request:

```
http://[ServerName]:8088/asterisk/mxml?action=Sippeers&actionid=SipPeersAction&SuppressEvents=True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It turns out that one of the extensions/trunks set inside the SIP file is causing reading the peers to crash, so the users is disconnected, and that's why you get permission denied afterward. So first comment all the extensions inside the sip file then try to run the sippeers actions, make sure it works, then start enabling extension gradually until you identify the extension that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using a custom code (http client) instead of browser and your client is not handling cookies properly! after the login request you must get cookie from asterisk response and save it for further use.

read more about ajam here
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=3578

and here is php based example that how to use cookies in custom request (http client)
http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/